# Show that $\cos(1 / x)$ cannot be continuously extended to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

> **Q:**
>   Show that $\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ cannot be continuously extended to $0$?
>
> Notice: use this Theorem
>
> Let $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $c\in D$. Then $f$ is continous at $c$ if and only if, whenever $X_n$ is a sequence in $D$ that converges to $c$, then $f(X_n)$ converges to $f(c)$.

I wish someone can solve this problem

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you find a sequence of values $t_n$ with $t_n\to\infty$ and $\cos(t_n)$ having no limit?  Can you see how you might use that sequence to solve your problem?

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence $X_n = \frac{1}{\pi n}$.

Comment: Then supposing $f$ _could_ be continuously extended, and taking $c=0$ in the theorem, what can be deduced about the value $f(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequences $$x_n = \dfrac1{2n \pi} \,\,\,\, \text{ and } x_n = \dfrac1{2 n \pi + \dfrac{\pi}2}$$ Both tend to zero. What happens to $\cos(1/x)$ along these sequences? (Recall that if a limit exists it has to be unique.)

Comment: thank you so much fried Marvis can you please explain more detail i need more explain thank you very much for helping